# How to remove visibility of variable while deserializing but enable visibility while serializing?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson2

How can I remove visibility of a variable in request but show in response?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with a single object.You can map request and response to two different Pojos as below:

```
public class Request{

 @JsonIngnore
 private int var1;
 private int var2;
//setters and getters

}

public class Response{

 private int var1;
 private int var2;
//setters and getters

}
```